# Haskell Data Model Visualization from Source

Tags: haskell, visualization, datamodel

Is there a tool that will automatically create a visualization (a class diagram sort of thing) of a haskell data model from source code? Something that walks down data constructors and records and shows the tree of types and fields and outputs a pretty image with boxes and such.

So, it would analyze source code such as:

```
data Type1 = Type1 Int Type2
data Type2 = Type2 { v1 :: Type3, v2 :: Type4, v3 :: String }
data Type3 = Type3 { v4 :: Double }
data Type4 = Type4 { v4 :: Type3 }
```

And it would generate a diagram from that with Type1 showing 2 attributes and linked to Type2 showing 3 attributes with their names and linked to Type3 and Type4, etc.

Comment: Btw, you might be interested in [SourceGraph](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SourceGraph) which generates various kinds of visualizations based on the source code...

Comment: Ah, SourceGraph looks great, but... I can't find the diagram I want in there. I want a data model diagram, but can't find it in the sample SourceGraph outputs.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes!**  [vacuum-cairo](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vacuum-cairo)

Comment: You should provide the name of the tool, instead of just saying "yes". That will prevent unnecessary iterations.

Comment: @Rog Try clicking the "Yes!". =)

Comment: Vacuum appears to be something that analyzes values at runtime. I'm looking for something that will analyze my source and create a full "class diagram" type of thing.